# Setting Value of Text Area

Tags: php, textarea

I m trying to set the value of a text area but it is not working correctly. I have verified that $bio has a value by echoing it in the beginning of my php file. However,  no text is displayed when trying to set the value of the text area. Does anyone know why?

Code for Text Area:

```
<form class="login" action="updatebio.php" form method="post">
<h3>Bio: </h3>
    <textarea  rows="12" cols="76" name="Bio" input id = "Bio" placeholder="Bio:" value="<?php echo                $bio; ?>" class = "textbox"  > </textarea>
    <input value="Update Bio" type="submit">

    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the value inside the tag

```
  <form class="login" action="updatebio.php" form method="post">
    <h3>Bio: </h3>
        <textarea  rows="12" cols="76" name="Bio" input id = "Bio" placeholder="Bio:" class = "textbox"  ><?php echo $bio; ?> </textarea>
        <input value="Update Bio" type="submit">

        </form>
```

Comment: Thats intresting, I presumed it worked like an input. Thanks! I'll vote you as best answer!

Answer (score 0):

Textarea does not work like a normal input box. The content between textarea is the content that will be in the box.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea

Answer (score 0):

text area does not take a value attribute. you have to place the value between the textarea tags

```
<textarea 
    rows="12" 
    cols="76" 
    name="Bio" 
    input 
    id = "Bio" 
    placeholder="Bio:" 
    class = "textbox">
<?php echo $bio; ?>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Textareas do not use "value". Put the data between the opening and closing tags.

```
<textarea><?php echo $bio; ?></textarea>
```